# how to get Apihost and ApiPath for CIM payment gethway method..?

Tags: php, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I want to need configure the Authorize.net - CIM Payment Get-way in my x-cart Platinum V 4.5.5 sites.

Now, Xpayments Modules are NOT support for my x-cart platinum Version 4.5.5.

So, i am start the Customization for Authorize.net - CIM Payment Get-way.

We have now use Test mode.

We have already this $g_loginname , $g_transactionkey

But,this $g_apihost and $g_apipath not available ,

so how to get Apihost and ApiPath for CIM Payment Getway method

https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/

$g_loginname ='xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$g_transactionkey ='xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$g_apihost = "apitest.authorize.net";
$g_apipath = "/xml/v1/request.api";

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The API host will depend if you're using the developer server or production server.

- Development server: `apitest.authorize.net`
- Production server: `api.authorize.net`

The API path is always `/xml/v1/request.api`

Comment: hello sir, i was test your suggestion but still can not GOT Any kind of Response for CIM Payment Get-way method. Can you please provide you more suggestion. - Thanks

Comment: There's no way we can help you troubleshoot it without seeing all of the code related to this. You probably should contact the software's support department or Authorize.Net for technical support.